# 'pargs' command in FreeBSD or Linux

Tags: linux, solaris, shell, freebsd, environment-variables

What's the FreeBSD (or Linux) equivalent to the 'pargs' command, available in Solaris? Many times I want to know what are the environment variables for a given process space, with no help from these systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute the PID where "12345" is shown:

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/12345/environ
```

or

```
ps eww -p 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete solution using ps version 3.39 on Ubuntu:

```
ps eww -p 12345 | tail -n 1 | awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) printf( "argv[%s]: %s\n", i-5, $i ); }'
```